# Derivative of $F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^3} \tan(xy^2) dy$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $x > 1$, and $F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^3} \tan(xy^2) dy$.

Then what is the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ ?

Then by applying Leibniz rule, we get $\frac{dF}{dx} = 3x^2 \tan(x^4) - 2x \tan(x^3)$.

And i got confused - 
Better here - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
After which I got -

$\frac{dF}{dx} = 3x^2 \tan(x^4) - 2x \tan(x^3) + \int_{x^2}^{x^3} y^2 \sec^2(xy^2) dy$

Is this correct? I also see that it's a definite integral where the integrand is of the form $\tan(ay^2)$ where $x$ can be treated as constant.

Comment: i got this here $$\int_{{x}^{2}}^{{x}^{3}}\!{y}^{2} \left( 1+ \left( \tan \left( x{y}^{2
} \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) \,{\rm d}y+3\,{x}^{2}\tan \left( {x}^{
7} \right) -2\,x\tan \left( {x}^{5} \right) 
$$

Comment: yes I was confused a bit, but while partial derivative wrt $x$ inside the integral in the last term of myn ? $sec^2$ must be there ?

Comment: note that $$\sec^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=...$$

Comment: :) oh a bit big expr. diverted me

Comment: Also is $x>1$ is required?

Comment: you Can also write this here $$-2 x \tan \left(x^5\right)+3 x^2 \tan
   \left(x^7\right)+\int_{x^2}^{x^3} y^2 \sec ^2\left(x
   y^2\right) \, dy$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, write

$$\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\tan xy^2\,dy=G(x^3)-G(x^2)\;,\;\;\text{with the primitive function}\;\;G'(t)=\tan xt^2\implies$$

$$F'(x)=3x^2G'(x^3)-2xG'(x^2)=3x^2\tan x^7-2x\tan x^5$$

Comment: If $G'(t) = tan(xt^2)$ then $G'(x^3) = tan(x^7)$!

Comment: @BAYMAX Great catch. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldnt it be $x^7$ and $x^5$ in your final answer ?

Comment: So discussions in the comments and for this answer we have one "additional term" remaining. that is $\int_{x^2}^{x^3} y^2 sec^2(xy^2) dy$ . How can we deal with that?

Comment: But here there is no extra term @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner  ?